# A highly musical rebus

Tags: rebus

What does the following rebus represent?

> Dso0+

The answer, as the title implies, is something musical.

Edit:

I realized the capital S was causing confusion. It doesn't matter whether it's capital or not, so I've changed it to lowercase.

Comment: DS = [Dal Segno](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dal_Segno) ?

Comment: Ugh, I can't stop thinking about Dark Souls when I look at it.

Comment: Is it about dark souls OST?

Comment: @fffred If so, the meaning of "0+" is clear, but how is o=al?

Comment: @BaSzAt, I'm not sure I see any relationship between DS and 0+ ...

Comment: @fffred Nevermind, I thought 0+ was a coda (cross within a circle), but apparently it's not.

Comment: @fffred then it wouldn't be a rebus, though

Comment: Is it a very weird notation for a chord, say Ds diminished with an extra “0th” degree note (so C double sharp?) augmented? So a chord with two D sharps? Are you talking about a lady musician who ability to dress with elegance is only matched by her generous bosoms?

Comment: Oooh, oooh, is it Mariah Carey? Some people would say that her singing abilities have decreased, or, say, diminished these later years. This started as a bad joke, but I’m actually starting to wonder…

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Sonata in D major
>
>  (so naught(0) *in* D+, with D+ meaning D major)
>
>  I updated this based on a comment, but I'm still not very confident in using D+ to mean "D major".

Or

> Solo (so low) in …
>
>  But if it doesn't matter whether "S" is capitalized or not, then so "so" wouldn't be as "low".

Comment: That's actually a very good idea !! Why not refine your answer with "D+" meaning "D major" thus having a sonata in D major ?

Comment: @ffred I thought of that, too, but I don't think I've ever seen D+ to mean D major.  I've see Dmaj and Dmin, D and d (using case), but D+ would be new to me.

Comment: Yes, but it's a rebus, not music notation ..... I guess

Comment: @ffred I updated my answer, but I've still got a note (heh) in there that I think D+ for D major is a bit odd.

Comment: Very Very Close. I "nada" the slang term for "nothing" in mind, rather than "naught", but I will definitely accept.

Comment: @RichardRoe so what did the + mean?

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor so0= sonata, which was "in" D+ meaning D Major.

Comment: @RichardRoe Is "+" standard notation for a major key? I can only seem to find it to mean augmented in chord notation.

Comment: @paste Perhaps not, but does it have to be? It makes sense after all, and someone else was able to solve it.

Comment: @RichardRoe No, it doesn't have to be. I was just curious where you got it from, because I didn't really understand the representation.

Answer (score 8):

I interpreted it as

> Dissonant
>  The first three characters can be pronounced "dee so". The zero can be interpreted as "none", and the plus sign resembles a 't'. Put those last two together phonetically to get "nunt". Saying these together, you get "dee so nunt" => Dissonant.

Answer (score 4):

Is this

> The lowest note, A1

Because

> The 'so' in Dso is the perfect fifth. Starting on note D, A would be its perfect fifth.
>  Then, 0+ would be an increment of 0 to 1.

Comment: Do you mean "sol"?

Comment: I've seen it like that, too, but I've always learned it as "so"

Comment: "so" is used sometimes, but historically it is "sol" as in "solfege"

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if it's relevant, but if you parse it as a

> chord notation,

you get

> "D suspended half-diminished diminished augmented chord" (which covers every note in the chromatic scale except D#, E and C#)

So it would be a fancy name for a

> [tone cluster](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tone_cluster)